# How to set and remove default Enter Click on my page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How to remove Default Enter Click from page.

that is Have one save button in my page that is Submit button.
When I click Enter its allways hitting save button. even If i am doing something else.

Can any body tell me how to remove this Default Enter click from my page.

Ex:

I have Grid with Filterable Columns

When I am doing Filter on the Grid its setting focus to Save button that is when I select anyting to filter from the Grid its allways setting focus to Save button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `e.preventDefault();` you can stop the default behavior

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)    // if it is enter
        e.preventDefault(); // stop default behavior
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way is replacing the submit button with ordinary button that submit the form with JS code when clicked:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="Submit" />
```

Downside is user won't be able to submit without JS enabled, so you can add the ordinary submit button within `<noscript>` tags.

Comment: thanks shadow. but when I do something else in my screen the focus is going to Save button.how do I need to remove this from my page?

Comment: just change the type from `submit` to `button`